# inet_aton similar function for IPv6 

Tags: python, ip, type-conversion, ipv6, inet

I am using `inet_aton` to convert IPv4 IP(216.12.207.142) to a string 3624718222. I use the following code for that:

```
ip_dec = unpack('>L', inet_aton(ip))[0]
```

Now I need to convert IPv6 ip 2001:23::207:142 to a similar string. It gives me error as it is not IPv4 address. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the code I've uses for the purpose before.  Note that it returns a 128 bit integer rather than a string (an integer is more useful in general)

```
from socket import inet_pton, AF_INET6
from struct import unpack

def ip6_to_integer(ip6):
    ip6 = inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip6)
    a, b = unpack(">QQ", ip6)
    return (a << 64) | b
```

And testing it

```
>>> ip6_to_integer("2001:23::207:142")
42540490934961530759802172199372521794L
```

Or as a string if you must!

```
>>> str(ip6_to_integer("2001:23::207:142"))
'42540490934961530759802172199372521794'
```